Forecasting a series that comes with uncertainty
I have a time series resulting from a spatiotemporal aggregation on the spatial domain.
As a result, I have a central measurement (let's say mean average) and a dispersion (let's say standard deviation).
If I want to do a traditional time-series forecasting, such as ARIMA, how should I encode the central measurement and the dispersion so the final model incorporates such uncertainties?
Should I treat the central measurement as the main series and the dispersion as an exogenous covariate? Should I create a series of the lower bound (let´s say mean - 2 standard deviations)? and then forecast it as a lower bound forecast?
I would like to know more about what the options may be.

The answer depends much on what you want to forecast and also on the
plausible models generating the data.
For the first aspect you may want to forecast the spatial average at a
future point in time or the random value at a specific point in time
and a specific point in the spatial domain, or even a quantity
depending on several points in the domain, possibly a random number of
these. Compared to the spatial average the resulting overdispersion
has to be anticipated.
For the second aspect, it may help to think of a spatio-temporal
process generating the data and to consider the effect of the spatial
aggregation. The spatio-temporal process could involve a point
process. Most likely you can use more than a single standard
deviation. For instance if the the spatial aggregation arises from
random events (storms, wildfires, accidents, ...) the intensity of
these events may be described in parametric form.
Even without further details on the context, it can be anticipated
that the quite general framework provided by state space models can
help. In these models the hidden or partially observed state vector
evolves in a Markovian fashion. The relation of the state to the (here
aggregated) observation can change in time. Investigating the
distribution of the state conditional on the observation is called
filtering or smoothing. ARIMA models are special cases of
state-space models but many appealing state space models can be derived
from geographical or physical considerations possibly using stochastic
differential equations.

Thanks for the suggestion of state space models. I have been thinking a bit in my use case (vegetation modelling) on the usage of Markov states that may help to  describe changes in non-stationary signals (such the one of vegetation of a natural forest over time).

It sounds like you may have entire probability distributions you would like to forecast. This is a case of functional-data-analysis. We don't have a lot on functional data forecasting; this thread may be interesting: Forecasting of density function. Apart from the Hyndman & Shang (2009) paper cited there, a more recent publication is Kokoszka et al. (2019). Unfortunately, I can't speak to the specific methods discussed there, but the papers and a search including "functional data forecasting" may be helpful.

Thanks a lot for the reference @stephan-kolassa . I will go over it, and bring more questions if they appear :)
